# Changing Colors using edge detection with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'd like to change the colors, well basically invert them.

Edge Detection outputs use a background with white lines and I would like the background to be white and the lines to be black.

Is this possible with opencv?

Answer (score 0):

```
//invert color
void invertColor(IplImage* src,IplImage* dst)
{
    unsigned char* pSrc=(unsigned char*)src->imageData;
    unsigned char* pDst=(unsigned char*)dst->imageData;
    for(int i=0;i<src->imageSize;i++){
        *pDst++=~*pSrc++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `cv.Not(src, dst)`. See the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvnot#void%20cvNot%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst%29)